# Kubernetes share a directory from your local system to kubernetes container

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Is there any way to share the directory/files to kubernetes container from your local system?

I have a deployment yaml file. I want to share the directory without using `kubectl cp`.

I tried with `configmap` but I later came to know that configmap can not have the whole directory but only a single file.

If anyone has any idea please share.

Please note: I do not want to host the file into minikube but I want to push the directory directly to container

Comment: You can create a PV and store the files there, accessing them in your cluster by mounting it as a volume in your pods. You can see the list of options [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/). Where is your cluster hosted?

Comment: @yanivoliver I am using minikube local system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mount local directory into pod in minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534980/mount-local-directory-into-pod-in-minikube)

Comment: You can use the [CIFS Flexvolume Plugin for Kubernetes](https://github.com/fstab/cifs). It will allow you to access a CIFS (SMB) network share

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found a way.

We can specify the directory we want to add into container by using `hostPath` in `volumes`

```
      volumeMounts:
        - name: crypto-config
          mountPath: <PATH IN CONTAINER>
        - name: channel-artifacts
          mountPath: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
        - name: chaincode
          mountPath: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
  volumes:
    - name: crypto-config
      hostPath:
        path: <YOUR LOCAL DIR PATH>
    - name: channel-artifacts
      hostPath:
        path: /Users/akshaysood/Blockchain/Kubernetes/Fabric/network/channel-artifacts
    - name: chaincode
      hostPath:
        path: /Users/akshaysood/Blockchain/Kubernetes/Fabric/network/chaincode
```

Comment: For the local dir Path, it is possible to use Relative Path ?

Comment: based on kubernetes documentation, this present a security risk:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath