# Kubernetes mount volume on existing directory with files inside the container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mount, kubernetes-pod

I am using k8s with version 1.11 and CephFS as storage.

I am trying to mount the directory created on the CephFS in the pod. To achieve the same I have written the following volume and volume mount config
in the deployment configuration

Volume

```
{
  "name": "cephfs-0",
  "cephfs": {
    "monitors": [
      "10.0.1.165:6789",
      "10.0.1.103:6789",
      "10.0.1.222:6789"
    ],
    "user": "cfs",
    "secretRef": {
      "name": "ceph-secret"
    },
    "readOnly": false,
    "path": "/cfs/data/conf"
  }
}
```

volumeMounts

```
{
  "mountPath": "/opt/myapplication/conf",
  "name": "cephfs-0",
  "readOnly": false
}
```

Mount is working properly. I can see the ceph directory i.e. /cfs/data/conf getting mounted on  /opt/myapplication/conf but following is my issue.

I have configuration files already present as a part of docker image at the location /opt/myapplication/conf. When deployment tries to mount the ceph volume then all the files at the location /opt/myapplication/conf gets disappear. I know it's the behavior of the mount operation but is there any way by which I would be able to persist the already existing files in the container on the volume which I am mounting so that other pod which is mounting the same volume can access the configuration files. i.e. the files which are already there inside the pod at the location /opt/myapplication/conf should be accessible on the CephFS at location /cfs/data/conf.

Is it possible?

I went through the docker document and it mentions that

> Populate a volume using a container
>   If you start a container which creates a new volume, as above, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted (such as /app/ above), the directory’s contents are copied into the volume. The container then mounts and uses the volume, and other containers which use the volume also have access to the pre-populated content.

This matches with my requirement but how to achieve it with k8s volumes?

Comment: Would https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/ work better for such config?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Unfortunately Kubernetes' volume system differs from Docker's, so this is not possible directly.

However, in case of a single file `foo.conf` you can use:

- a `mountPath` ending in this file name and
- a `subPath` containing this file name, like this:

```yaml
    volumeMounts:
    - name: cephfs-0
      mountPath: /opt/myapplication/conf/foo.conf
      subPath: foo.conf
```

Repeat that for each file. But if you have a lot of them, or if their names can vary, then you have to handle this at runtime or use templating tools. Usually that means mounting it somewhere else and setting up symlinks before your main process starts.

Comment: there's a way to share host file to pods
[kubernetes share a directory from your local system to kubernetes container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037957/kubernetes-share-a-directory-from-your-local-system-to-kubernetes-container)

Comment: @sngjuk Yes, that's not the issue. The hard part here is that Docker has a feature to initialize a persistent volume with content from a container image. Kubernetes does not have this feature.

Comment: Note that this option makes, at least Ruby, failing at updating the file is seen as a directory: `/application/config/initializers/clamby.rb:11:in \`initialize': Is a directory @ rb_sysopen - /application/config/clamby.conf (Errno::EISDIR)`

Comment: This mounts as directory not as file.

Answer (score 5):

Very easy ! you have to use init container here. With init container use the same deployment image of your application.
Assuming your container path is /opt/myapplication/conf
your init container will share the cephfs PVC

1. with init container define volume mount at /opt/data
2. in init container config run the command mv to move your existing data to mounted volume path /opt/data.

with main application container, mount the volume at correct location i.e. /opt/myapplication/conf

now when you deploy your application,

- your init container mounts the cephfs pv and moves container path data to volume.
- now your main application starts and mounts the volume on correct path , now the volume when mounting here have data also.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by having my `ENTRYPOINT` be a bash script that `mv` my config files i wanted mounted to their correct location. It seems `this device or resource is busy` errors were happening because the files were not mounted yet.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this very niche issue not being able to mount a folder to a specific path with content from my built image. This ends up empty.

However my workaround is to use ENTRYPOINT in de dockerfile refering to a shellscript that runs the commands to initialize DB or do something with files that affects the mounted target folder.

So it seems that entrypoint runs after the volume is being mounted by kubernetes.

I did tried to symlink the path in the entrypoint script, but that didn't work out.