# Copying file from host laptop(mac) to dynamically created kubernetes pod via Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, minikube

I installed `minikube` and started `Jenkins` inside a `pod`. I am able to create a new job and execute it inside a dynamically created `maven container`. However. I have a folder in my `host` machine which is a `Mac` based and I need that folder inside this dynamically created `pod` when the job is started. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you tied `kubectl cp` command?

Comment: unfortunately the container that I have started does not have kubectl installed and I don't have the luxury to install that either.

Comment: I mean running kubectl from you MAC host, let me add the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/#interacting-with-your-cluster

configure kubectl on your MAC, then use `kubectl cp <hostdir> <podname>:<dir>`

Option 2.

use the Host path option for POD, like this post

[Mount local directory into pod in minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534980/mount-local-directory-into-pod-in-minikube)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest solution is to push that folder as git repo ( if it is not large ) to either github or your private git server , and then clone it as a first step in your jenkins job.

Comment: I have done this before. It was so easy. But now I cannot push it because it has some sensitive information. :(