# What are the differences between a 9P and hostPath mount in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am looking to do local dev of an app that is running in Kubernetes on minikube. I want to mount a local directory to speed up development, so I can make code changes to my app (python) without rebuilding the container.

If I understand correctly, I have two out of the box options:

1. [9P mount](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/) which is provided by minikube
2. [hostPath mount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) which comes directly from Kubernetes

What are the differences between these, and in what cases would one be appropriate over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[9P mount](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/#9p-mounts) and [hostPath](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/)  are two different concepts. You cannot mount directory to pod using 9P mount.

9P mount is used to mount host directory into the minikube VM.

HostPath is a persistent volume which mounts a file or directory from the host node's(in your case minikube VM) filesystem into your Pod.

Take a look also on types of Persistent Volumes: [pv-types-k8s](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/%23types-of-persistent-volumes&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1604583607939000&usg=AFQjCNHDuPV6-f5R7hLBJD0pSU1vJS5wRQ).

**If you want to mount a local directory to pod:**

First, you need to mount your directory  for example: `$HOME/your/path`  into your minikube VM using [9P](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/). Execute command:

```
$ minikube start --mount-string="$HOME/your/path:/data"
```

Then if you mount  `/data`  into your Pod using [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume), you will get you local directory data into Pod.

**Another solution**:

Mount host's  `$HOME`  directory  into minikube's  `/hosthome`  directory. Get your data:

```
$ ls -la /hosthome/your/path
```

To mount this directory, you have to just change your Pod's hostPath

```
hostPath:
  path: /hosthome/your/path
```

Take a look: [minikube-mount-data-into-pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534980/mount-local-directory-into-pod-in-minikube).

Also you need to know that:

> Minikube is configured to persist files stored under the following
> directories, which are made in the Minikube VM (or on your localhost
> if running on bare metal). You may lose data from other directories on
> reboots.

More: [note-persistence-minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/#a-note-on-mounts-persistence-and-minikube-hosts).

See [driver-mounts](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/#driver-mounts) as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks. Great explanation!