# kubernetes how to make a folder on my host as a Persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes

I am running a kuberneted cluster using minikube.

I want to mount a folder from my PC into the minikube.

How can i do that.

I see there is `hostPath`, but that used the node inside minikube

Just like in docker-compose we can mount a host folder into the container, is there any such provision

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534980/mount-local-directory-into-pod-in-minikube) answer your question? If not, could you please describe the environment in which minikube is running?

Answer (score 0):

@Santhosh If i understand your question correctly, do you want to mount a path from within a container to a PV of type hostpath on your host? Have you tried this :-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pv-recycler
  namespace: default
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: vol
    hostPath:
      path: /any/path/it/will/be/replaced
  containers:
  - name: pv-recycler
    image: "k8s.gcr.io/busybox"
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "test -e /scrub && rm -rf /scrub/..?* /scrub/.[!.]* /scrub/*  && test -z \"$(ls -A /scrub)\" || exit 1"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: vol
      mountPath: /scrub
```

Comment: `hostPath: path: /any/path/it/will/be/replaced`  so you mean i can use the path on my local pc here directly.