# Minikube mount hostpath

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube, mount

I'm trying to mount a local folder onto minikube for persisting jenkins data but its failing with below error.
idea is to run jenkins on minikube cluster with persistent data for its workspace.
minikube version and kubernetes version is mentioned below along with error logs.

```
'$ minikube mount "/home/sourabh/jenkins_data:/jenkins_data"
  Mounting host path /home/sourabh/jenkins_data into VM as /jenkins_data ...
    ▪ Mount type:
    ▪ User ID:      docker
    ▪ Group ID:     docker
    ▪ Version:      9p2000.L
    ▪ Message Size: 262144
    ▪ Options:      map[]
    ▪ Bind Address: 172.19.196.135:38837
  Userspace file server: ufs starting

❌  Exiting due to GUEST_MOUNT_COULD_NOT_CONNECT: /bin/bash -c "sudo mount -t 9p -o dfltgid=$(grep ^docker: /etc/group | cut -d: -f3),dfltuid=$(id -u docker),msize=262144,port=38837,trans=tcp,version=9p2000.L 172.19.196.135 /jenkins_data": Process exited with status 32
stdout:

stderr:
mount: /jenkins_data: mount(2) system call failed: Connection timed out.

  Suggestion:

    If the host has a firewall:

    1. Allow a port through the firewall
    2. Specify "--port=<port_number>" for "minikube mount"

╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                           │
│      If the above advice does not help, please let us know:                             │
│      https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose                           │
│                                                                                           │
│    Please run `minikube logs --file=logs.txt` and attach logs.txt to the GitHub issue.    │
│    Please also attach the following file to the GitHub issue:                             │
│    - /tmp/minikube_mount_a057c2cb7d52cb75588bb40c4af93fe409b78381_0.log                   │
│                                                                                           │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

Logfile generate shown here

Binary: Built with gc go1.19.2 for linux/amd64
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
I0109 16:36:07.842613    2616 out.go:296] Setting OutFile to fd 1 ...
I0109 16:36:07.842751    2616 out.go:348] isatty.IsTerminal(1) = true
I0109 16:36:07.842754    2616 out.go:309] Setting ErrFile to fd 2...
I0109 16:36:07.842757    2616 out.go:348] isatty.IsTerminal(2) = true
I0109 16:36:07.842890    2616 root.go:334] Updating PATH: /home/sourabh/.minikube/bin
W0109 16:36:07.842980    2616 root.go:311] Error reading config file at /home/sourabh/.minikube/config/config.json: open /home/sourabh/.minikube/config/config.json: no such file or directory
I0109 16:36:07.843091    2616 mustload.go:65] Loading cluster: minikube
I0109 16:36:07.843369    2616 config.go:180] Loaded profile config "minikube": Driver=docker, ContainerRuntime=docker, KubernetesVersion=v1.25.3
I0109 16:36:07.843676    2616 cli_runner.go:164] Run: docker container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}
I0109 16:36:07.914497    2616 host.go:66] Checking if "minikube" exists ...
I0109 16:36:07.914672    2616 cli_runner.go:164] Run: docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "8443/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube
I0109 16:36:07.978854    2616 mount.go:141] Selecting IP for WSL. This may be incorrect...
I0109 16:36:07.983207    2616 out.go:177]   Mounting host path /home/sourabh/jenkins_data into VM as /jenkins_data ...
I0109 16:36:07.987688    2616 out.go:177]     ▪ Mount type:
I0109 16:36:07.992029    2616 out.go:177]     ▪ User ID:      docker
I0109 16:36:07.996174    2616 out.go:177]     ▪ Group ID:     docker
I0109 16:36:08.000666    2616 out.go:177]     ▪ Version:      9p2000.L
I0109 16:36:08.005048    2616 out.go:177]     ▪ Message Size: 262144
I0109 16:36:08.009032    2616 out.go:177]     ▪ Options:      map[]
I0109 16:36:08.012980    2616 out.go:177]     ▪ Bind Address: 172.19.196.135:46487
I0109 16:36:08.017007    2616 out.go:177]   Userspace file server:
I0109 16:36:08.016686    2616 ssh_runner.go:195] Run: /bin/bash -c "[ "x$(findmnt -T /jenkins_data | grep /jenkins_data)" != "x" ] && sudo umount -f /jenkins_data || echo "
I0109 16:36:08.017091    2616 cli_runner.go:164] Run: docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube
I0109 16:36:08.087038    2616 sshutil.go:53] new ssh client: &{IP:127.0.0.1 Port:61875 SSHKeyPath:/home/sourabh/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa Username:docker}
I0109 16:36:08.127492    2616 mount.go:168] unmount for /jenkins_data ran successfully
I0109 16:36:08.127507    2616 ssh_runner.go:195] Run: /bin/bash -c "sudo mkdir -p /jenkins_data"
I0109 16:36:08.135776    2616 ssh_runner.go:195] Run: /bin/bash -c "sudo mount -t 9p -o dfltgid=$(grep ^docker: /etc/group | cut -d: -f3),dfltuid=$(id -u docker),msize=262144,port=46487,trans=tcp,version=9p2000.L 172.19.196.135 /jenkins_data"
I0109 16:37:31.315966    2616 out.go:177]   Unmounting /jenkins_data ...
I0109 16:37:31.322056    2616 ssh_runner.go:195] Run: /bin/bash -c "[ "x$(findmnt -T /jenkins_data | grep /jenkins_data)" != "x" ] && sudo umount -f /jenkins_data || echo "
Log file created at: 2023/01/09 16:38:06
Running on machine: Sourabh_PC
Binary: Built with gc go1.19.2 for linux/amd64
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
I0109 16:38:06.875663    2694 out.go:296] Setting OutFile to fd 1 ...
I0109 16:38:06.875853    2694 out.go:348] isatty.IsTerminal(1) = true


OS
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"

running minikube version 1.28
kuberneter 1.23.0`
```

Tried looking for other possible options but nothing is availble online related to this issue.

Comment: try this once @Sy-py https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534980/mount-local-directory-into-pod-in-minikube

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing a similar issue and I believe the issue has to do with certification errors. When you work behind a VPN, proxy, or corporate environment or VM you will sometimes be using certifications that are not relevant to the container and that means you will not be able to communicate outside of it.

To solve the issue I would try looking into mounting your certification directory from local onto the container certification's directory and running `update-ca-certificates`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was due to `ufw` firewall

Had to allow a port:

```
sudo ufw allow 40000
```

Then mount using the allowed port

```
minikube mount --port=40000  /my/local/project:/my/minikube/project
```