# Setting volumes on minikube to local development

Tags: docker, minikube

I started minikube this way

```
minikube start driver=docker
```

then I mounted a local folder into minikube

```
minikube mount /home/user/prueba-kubernetes/src:/home/docker/src
```

and it works I can see the local folder content inside  minikube container.

The I created  a volume,a volumeclaim a deployment and a service

volume.yaml file

```
 apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolume
    metadata:
      name: pvc0003
    spec:
      capacity:
        storage: 1Gi
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      hostPath:
        path: /home/docker/src
```

volume-claim.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc0003
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache-php-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache-php
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache-php
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: apache-php
        image: httpd:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: volume
          mountPath: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
      volumes:
      - name: volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc0003
```

service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apache-php-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: apache-php
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30080
```

the server is working but is not showing `/home/user/prueba-kubernetes/src/index.html` of my local folder

its shomething wrong on this config?

Comment: Why use Kubernetes (normally a distributed, replicated, multi-node container environment) in this setup?  Can you use plain Docker without Kubernetes; or do you need a container at all?

Comment: it's for learning purpose, I know docker its enough for this setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534980/mount-local-directory-into-pod-in-minikube) on how to mount local directory on minikube cluster.

Also, there are driver mounts that you may want to check if supported via this [link](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/#driver-mounts)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache-php-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache-php
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache-php
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: apache-php
        image: httpd:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: volume
          mountPath: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
      volumes:
        - name: volume
          hostPath:
            path: /home/docker/src
            type: Directory
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apache-php-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: apache-php
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30080
```